# SQL Server : using a dynamic column name as the expression in PATINDEX()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to do something like this

```
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(400) = 'name'
SELECT PATINDEX ('%b%', @ColumnName)  AS Test FROM Table
```

The problem I am having is that the `PATINDEX` expression is using the literal "name" as the source and not the data in the column. Is there a way to use a dynamic variable as the column itself?

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @SQL VarChar(2000)
DECLARE @ColumnName VarChar(400) = 'name'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT PATINDEX(''%b'',' + @ColumnName + ') AS Test FROM Table'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I was doing some dynamic SQL first but I had the quote scenario incorrect. Thanks again!

Comment: if original query has problem I think wrapping(exactly the original query) and executing it using dynamic sql will have problem also

Answer (score -1):

Not clear what you are asking. My interpretation

SELECT PATINDEX ('%b%', column_name)  AS Test FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Table'

Comment: this answer is not related with the problem which is mentioned in question